# How to schedule multiple CronJobs using bash without conflicting each other?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have 4 Jobs, which run at different intervals. How can I prevent them from conflicting each other? Job 2,3,4 can only be run one at a time. Any new job invocation must wait for old completion before beginning.

```
0 9,11,14 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/userName/Desktop/Auto/job_1.sh   
0 8-17 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/userName/Desktop/Auto/job_2.sh
*/6 * * * * /bin/bash /home/userName/Desktop/Auto/job_3.sh
*/20 * * * * /bin/bash /home/userName/Desktop/Auto/job_4.sh
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just integrate  `[[ pgrep  job_x >/dev/null  2>&1 ]] && exit` at the top of each of them and make sure they exit if any of the others are running ...

Comment: Thanks for answer! I don't want to exit if others are running, it should behave something like a queue.
Say its 5PM, Job_2 will start running first (because of list order), Job_3 & Job_4 should be in a queue, if Job_2 takes more than 10 mins for running, then again Job_3 should be enqueued and resulting like
Queue = Job_3, Job_4, Job_3

Comment: No, that's not going to work w/ cron ... hence my suggestion.And given the different times at which they're supposed to fire running them as a string of command won't work, either.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using `flock`.
You have to install `util-linux` to get flock.
It has lots of options like timeout, etc.
Your crontab could look something like this:

```
0 9,11,14 * * 1-5 flock -x /tmp/cronjobs.lock -c '/bin/bash /home/userName/Desktop/Auto/job_1.sh'
0 8-17 * * 1-5 flock -x /tmp/cronjobs.lock -c '/bin/bash /home/userName/Desktop/Auto/job_2.sh'
*/6 * * * * flock -x /tmp/cronjobs.lock -c '/bin/bash /home/userName/Desktop/Auto/job_3.sh'
*/20 * * * * flock -x /tmp/cronjobs.lock -c '/bin/bash /home/userName/Desktop/Auto/job_4.sh'
```

The syntax for flock is:
`flock -x <lockfile> -c '<command>'`
The lockfile is a file that is locked on your machine. Each new command will check to see if that file is locked by a previous command. Once that previous command finishes, it releases the lock and the next command can run, taking out a new lock.
Using the `-w <seconds>` command you can tell flock the time in seconds to wait while trying to take out a lock on the file before the command fails and does not run.
For instance, the following would wait 3 minutes for previous cron job to finish. If it did not finish in that time then the command below would not run.

`*/20 * * * * flock -w 180 -x /tmp/cronjobs.lock -c '/bin/bash /home/userName/Desktop/Auto/job_4.sh'`

Comment: Thanks for replying!
Will flock form a queue automatically for jobs that aren't able to run because of lockfile present?
Ex: If its 5PM, Job 2,3 & 4 should run, naturally Job 2 will run first because of order, and file is locked. Will Job 3 & 4 will be queued seeing that previous job has locked the file? So, once Job 2 finishes, it automatically runs Job_3 and Job_4 after that ?

Comment: No, it won't. You can't have things "running" at set different intervals and expect them to run in a queue, especially not with completely different demands on "hours" and "days" - that's impossible without a complex hand-knit solution. @Lastwish

Comment: As @tink said, the waiting jobs for flock could be processed in a random order. If I understand, job_1.sh doesn't conflict so just create regular cron entry. Combine jobs 3 & 4 into a single script and use flock for job_2 and also the combined 3&4. That way there is only ever 1 job waiting.